# Matasano challenge Python Set 1-> 3, unknown errors in code

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm trying to solve the Matasano challenge set 1-> 3 that is Single-byte XOR cipher and reverse it . I think i understand the concept to solve but my solution is giving some errors :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\crypto\python\breakXor.py", line 59, in <module>
 print(transforma(unhex))
File "C:\crypto\python\breakXor.py", line 51, in transforma
 if(scoreBoard(xored) > r):
File "C:\crypto\python\breakXor.py", line 40, in scoreBoard
 c=chr(i).lower()
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I'm given this erros and i dont really understand why

```
import binascii

freqs = {
'a': 0.08167,
'b': 0.01492,
'c': 0.02782,
'd': 0.04253,
'e': 0.12702,
'f': 0.02228,
'g': 0.02015,
'h': 0.06094,
'i': 0.06966,
'j': 0.00153,
'k': 0.00772,
'l': 0.04025,
'm': 0.02406,
'n': 0.06749,
'o': 0.07507,
'p': 0.01929,
'q': 0.00095,
'r': 0.05987,
's': 0.06327,
't': 0.09056,
'u': 0.02758,
'v': 0.00978,
'w': 0.02361,
'x': 0.00150,
'y': 0.01974,
'z': 0.00074,
' ': 0.19281 
}

def xor(xs, ys):
    return "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for x, y in zip(xs, ys))


def scoreBoard(inp):
    r = 0
    for i in inp:
        c=chr(i).lower()
        if c in freqs :
            r += freqs[c]
    return r 



def transforma(inp):
    r = 0  
    for i in range(0,256):
        xored = xor(inp,list(str(i)))
        if(scoreBoard(xored) > r):
            resultado = scoreBoard(xored)
            indice = i 
    return (indice,resultado)

if __name__  ==  "__main__":
    inp = '1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736'
    unhex = binascii.unhexlify(inp) 
    print(transforma(unhex))
```

Any improvements to the solution of an explanation for the erros and how to fix them would be awesome

Ps : i'm a noob in python and in OOP so any advise is welcome

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler thats done used a list(str(i)) to fix it . gonna update the errors

Comment: If `i` is a number, you can int(i), so try chr(int(i))

Answer (score 0):

xor is expecting 2 lists; you are passing it a list and an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is wrong, the `scoreBoard` similar this, refs [Matasano-Crypto-Challenges from github](https://github.com/tomdeakin/Matasano-Crypto-Challenges/blob/master/textutils.py)

```
def scoreBoard(text):
    text = text.upper()
    frequencies = {}
    for letter in text:
        if letter in frequencies:
            frequencies[letter] += 1.
        else:
            frequencies[letter] = 1.

    total = sum(frequencies.values())
    for letter in frequencies.keys():
        frequencies[letter] /= total

    score = 0.0
    for l in freqs.keys():
        if l not in frequencies:
            frequencies[l] = 0.0
        score += math.sqrt(frequencies[l] * freqs[l])

    return score
```

Comment: I dont understand why my algorithm would be wrong , care for explain ?